# Path of template in js file in Symfony/angular project

Tags: javascript, angularjs, symfony, assets

i working on an AngularJS/Symfony project and I cant figure out how to define correctly the path of a twig template in my js.

The path to: -the original JS
             -the template
             -the JS path with assetic

```
    ...
    +-src/
   | +-MyCompany/
   |   +-MyBundle/
   |     +-Resources/
   |       +-public/
   |         +-js/
   |           +-directive/
   |             +-my_file.js
   |       +-view/
   |         +-template/
   |            my_template.html.twig  
   +-web/
   | bundles/
   |   +-MyBundle/
   |     +-js/
   |       +-my_fil.js
   ...
```

My js code:

```
return {
    templateUrl: '?'
}
```

So, is there a way to include a path from a bundle into an asset file? (I tried the @bundle/ notation, but didnt work).
Or, when I include the js in my html, to use the js of the bundle and not the one of the asset?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

That would be

```
{% javascripts filter='?uglifyjs2'
    '@AppBundle/Resources/assets/js/your-file.js'
    '@AppBundle/Resources/assets/js/your-second-file.js'
    '@AppBundle/Resources/assets/js/admin-*.js'
%}
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset(asset_url) }}"></script>
{% endjavascripts %}
```

The filter allows you to apply, for instance, `UglifyJS` in this example. The path points to `src/AppBundle/Resouces/assets/js/` and will combine the two files. It's even possible to use wildcards.